# Is every completely regular topology induced by some topological vector space?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, topological-vector-spaces, separation-axioms

Every topological vector space is completely regular.  My question is, is the converse true?  That is, is every completely regular topology induced by some topological vector space?

If not, does anyone know of a counterexample?

Comment: isn't every metric space completely regular? in which case, $\{0,1\}$......

Comment: So there are obvious counterexamples to the statement "If $X$ is completely regular, then $X$ is a topological vector space".  Do you perhaps want a proof/contradiction to the statement "If $X$ is completely regular, then $X$ embeds in a topological vector space"?

Comment: @DanRust Well, $\{0,1\}$ is a ($1$-dimensional) topological vector space over the (discrete) topological field $\mathbb{F}_2$. But a discrete space with $6$ points does the trick, since any finite vector space has prime power order.

Comment: @AlexKruckman good point. I was just thinking about real/complex coefficients. I think Aweygan's question is maybe more what OP was aiming for though.

Comment: Just in case the question was intended to be as @Aweygan suggested: Every completely regular space embeds into a power of the interval $[0,1]$ with the product topology. (This is the main step in one construction of the Stone-Cech compactification.) So it embeds into a power of $\mathbb R$, which is a topological vector space.

Comment: @AndreasBlass You should give an official answer. I didn't read your comment and wrote an answer - and then detected it is the same as you said.

Comment: @PaulFrost OK, I've copied my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case the question was intended to be as @Aweygan suggested: Every completely regular space embeds into a power of the interval [0,1] with the product topology. (This is the main step in one construction of the Stone-Cech compactification.) So it embeds into a power of ℝ, which is a topological vector space.